# State not being updated in React.js

Tags: javascript, react-state-management, react-state, reactjs

I have created a basic form in react.js where I am able to get the values after the user submits the form.

However, when I try to change the values using the `handleSubmit` function, I don't see the changes made in the state.

I have made a copy of a state and changes are being reflected in the Copied State. But when I set the old state equal to the updated state, the changes are not reflected

My code is as follows

```
    state = {    
        name: null,
        ContactNumber: null

    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name] : event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        let Copystate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state))
        Copystate.ContactNumber = 100

        console.log(Copystate) // displaying the contact number as 100

        this.setState({
            state : Copystate
        })

        console.log(this.state) // displays the number which was submitted in the form

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>Form</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" required = {true} onChange = {this.handleChange}/>

                        <label>Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="number" name="ContactNumber" required = {true} onChange = {this.handleChange}/>

                        <button type="submit" label="submit" >Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice: setState is asynchronous: document [state-updates-may-be-asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

You can use a callback function to get the updated state

```
this.setState({state: Copystate}, () => {console.log(this.state)});
```

Or you can choose to use `async/await`

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  await this.setState({state: Copystate});
  console.log(this.state);
}
```

Those two methods won't affect re-render since once the state is been updated, the re-render would proceed.

If you `console` in the `render()` you would find that it should always be updated finally.

```
render() {
  console.log(this.state);
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous.
So, you can do one of the following -
 1. make a callback in setState to log the state or
 2. write your console statement in the render function.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do this?

```
let Copystate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state))
Copystate.ContactNumber = 100
```

You can change the `handleSubmit` to be like the following:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let { ContactNumber } = this.state;
        ContactNumber = 100;

        console.log(ContactNumber); // displaying the contact number as 100

        this.setState({
            ContactNumber: ContactNumber
        }, () => {
           console.log(this.state) // displays the number which was submitted in the form
        })
    }
```